# Can't activate projected type defined in IDL

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I was trying to define a Windows Runtime type in IDL, and consume its projected type. Going from a default-generated *Blank App* UWP project (called *"Blank App"*), I added *"MyControl.idl"*:

```
namespace BlankApp
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MyControl : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control
    {
        MyControl();
    }
}
```

Compiled the solution, then copied *MyControl.h* and *MyControl.cpp* from *Generated Files/sources* to the project root directory.

I included the header for the projected type and added the following code to `App::OnLaunched`:

```cpp
#include <winrt/BlankApp.h>

...

void App::OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs const& e)
{
    auto const myControl{ winrt::BlankApp::MyControl() };
    ...
```

This all compiled and linked fine. At runtime, it throws an `hresult_error` (0x80040154: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered).

The top of the callstack at the point the exception is raised looks like this:

> ```
> BlankApp.exe!winrt::hresult_error::hresult_error(const HRESULT code=REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered, winrt::hresult_error::from_abi_t __formal={...}) Line 2977  C++ Symbols loaded.
> BlankApp.exe!winrt::throw_hresult(const HRESULT result=REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered) Line 3211  C++ Symbols loaded.
> BlankApp.exe!winrt::check_hresult(HRESULT result=REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered) Line 3261    C++ Symbols loaded.
> BlankApp.exe!winrt::impl::get_activation_factory<winrt::BlankApp::MyControl,winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory>() Line 7375 C++ Symbols loaded.
> BlankApp.exe!winrt::impl::factory_cache_entry<winrt::BlankApp::MyControl,winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory>::get() Line 7448   C++ Symbols loaded.
> BlankApp.exe!winrt::get_activation_factory<winrt::BlankApp::MyControl,winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory>() Line 7520   C++ Symbols loaded.
> BlankApp.exe!winrt::BlankApp::MyControl::MyControl() Line 74    C++ Symbols loaded.
> BlankApp.exe!winrt::BlankApp::implementation::App::OnLaunched(const winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::LaunchActivatedEventArgs & e={...}) Line 50   C++ Symbols loaded.
> ```

*module.g.cpp* is compiled into the application and contains the following code:

```cpp
HRESULT __stdcall WINRT_GetActivationFactory(HSTRING classId, void** factory)
{
    try
    {
        *factory = nullptr;
        wchar_t const* const name = WindowsGetStringRawBuffer(classId, nullptr);

        if (0 == wcscmp(name, L"BlankApp.MainPage"))
        {
            *factory = winrt::detach_abi(winrt::make<winrt::BlankApp::factory_implementation::MainPage>());
            return S_OK;
        }

        if (0 == wcscmp(name, L"BlankApp.MyControl"))
        {
            *factory = winrt::detach_abi(winrt::make<winrt::BlankApp::factory_implementation::MyControl>());
            return S_OK;
        }

#ifdef _WRL_MODULE_H_
        return ::Microsoft::WRL::Module<::Microsoft::WRL::InProc>::GetModule().GetActivationFactory(classId, reinterpret_cast<::IActivationFactory**>(factory));
#else
        return winrt::hresult_class_not_available().to_abi();
#endif
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return winrt::to_hresult();
    }
}
```

So apparently, my type wasn't registered for lookup by the Windows Runtime, even though everything seems to be where it needs to be. Is there some registration step I'm missing? Or is this even supported from a UWP application as opposed to a Windows Runtime Component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add the class to the appx manifest.

There's an example in the [Extensions element documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-extensions). The following [Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-extension) element needs to be added:

```xml
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
    <InProcessServer>
      <Path>BlankApp.exe</Path>
      <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="BlankApp.MyControl" ThreadingModel="both" />
    </InProcessServer>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

To allow the Windows Runtime to retrieve an activation factory, the `DllGetActivationFactory` symbol needs to be exported from the executable as well. This can be done by adding the following .def file to the project:

```def
EXPORTS
DllCanUnloadNow = WINRT_CanUnloadNow                    PRIVATE
DllGetActivationFactory = WINRT_GetActivationFactory    PRIVATE
```

Comment: Adding an `<Extension>` element for an `<InProcessServer>` (specifying the path to the executable, as well as the type name/threading model) changed the error to 0x800401F9 (`CO_E_ERRORINDLL`). Presumably, the `WINRT_GetActivationFactory` symbol needs to be exported (like it is in a Windows Runtime Component). Forcing that export doesn't change the result, though. The attempt to activate the type fails with error code 0x800401F9.

Comment: My bad, I was exporting the decorated symbols. Using a .def file to export `DllGetActivationFactory` (and `DllCanUnloadNow`) appears to have fixed the issue. I'm not sure if this is safe, or whether there are other ways to get the desired functionality.

Comment: The def file is the supported way to map these exports. If you install the VSIX from the marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264) and create a "New Windows Runtime Component (C++ /WinRT)" project, you'll see that the def file gets created for you as part of the template.

Comment: I know, that using a .def file is the supported way to export symbols from an executable image. What I am worried about is, whether exporting those symbols from an app (vs. a component) is safe. It just doesn't feel right to declare an extensibility point for a type, that's internal to the app's implementation. I also don't know, what's special about components, so that they are respected for type factory lookup by the system, without an .appxmanifest.

Comment: Manually exporting the `Dll*` symbols doesn't appear to be required (anymore?). Those exports are provided by the generated file `App.xaml.g.hpp` by way of `#pragma` directives. I don't know, whether this is due to an updated VSIX toolchain, or whether something changed in my project that caused the .hpp file to get pulled in.