# Invoke c++WinRt Run time class from C#

Tags: interop, c++-winrt

Given the changes in windows platform of recent and C++Winrt being its own platform , what is the latest greatest way to bidirectional introp with C# from c++ Winrt project.

1. Currently there is no DLL project template for Winrt, is that cause the future is Run-time time components, and we should not be expecting winrt dll project.
2. is there a winrt example that shows implementation and consumption of c++ winrt runtime component.
3. Can i still use pinvoke from c# into c++ winrt project, any perf info regards pinvoke compared to runtime component.
4. what about reverse pinvoke, given there is no dll project   type for winrt
5. Any winrt c++ specifics regards marshalling
6. What about hosting managed context API provided by dotnet, is there equivalent accessible form Winrt::Windows. To be used by C++ Winrt app calling C# API. I think the class name in .Net is ClrRunTimeHost, is this in winrt::windows.

Cheers

Comment: C++/WinRT is not a platform; it's a language projection for the Windows Runtime. There *is* a project template for a DLL, too. It's called *"Windows Runtime Component (C++/WinRT)"*. You'll find samples of authoring and consuming Windows Runtime components at https://aka.ms/cppwinrt. You cannot use P/Invoke to access a Windows Runtime type (or at least it would be unreasonable to do so). You don't need to host the CLR to access a Windows Runtime component authored with C#.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. For example i have implemented the bookstore winrt example, and i have booktype defined in IDL accessed by xaml for gui. Is it possible to reuse that  same book type from another project in C#, or do i stilll need to create run time component even though its C# invoking  winrt type.  All the example i see only access winrt run time class from Xaml in same  project not from another project like say C# project. thank you.

Comment: Basically if you already have a run-time class in one c++ winrt project being accessed by xaml in same project, can i use a winmd reference  to same run-time class from a separate C# project. Or do i need run-time component for that.

Comment: I have referenced winmd for my run-time class in C#, builds and fails saying my class is not registered. I am using the type directly from another winrt BlankApp project, its not packaged in run-time component template. Question is will it work , or do i always have to use run-time component for interop

Comment: To reference a type from a module, that isn't a Windows Runtime Component, you'll have to add an `Extensions` element to you .appxmanifest (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50898168/1889329)). I don't know, why this works, nor why it works this way, so I'll just recommend to choose the canonical solution: Implement reusable types in Windows Runtime Components. Is there any particular reason, why you do not want to create a component?

Comment: Thanks IInspectable, just checking cause dont want to bother with component for very small interop.  But using the component now and miles better than pinvoke. Now got to see if there will be any need for marshaling. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Marshaling is automatic. You can only have Windows Runtime types in your Windows Runtime component interfaces, so the Windows Runtime knows how to marshal those types already.