# Naivgating to a page using the XAML Hosting API in a Win32 program causes an access violation

Tags: c++, winapi, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I'm using the XAML hosting API to host XAML content in my win32 program. I have successfully initialized the hosting framework and created `DesktopWindowXamlSource` objects. I have set the `Content()` of my `DesktopWindowXamlSource` to a `Frame.` My problem occurs whenever I try to navigate to a page with that `Frame`.

To create a `Page` for my program to use, I followed these steps:

1. Make IDL definition

   ```
   namespace Program
   {
       [default_interface]
       runtimeclass SettingsPage: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
       {
           SettingsPage();
       }
   }
   ```
2. I build the project, copy the generated header and source file from `project_root_folder\Debug\Generated Files\sources` to the project's root. I then add the files using the Solution Explorer.
3. I delete the `static_assert` from each of the files.
4. I build the project, then I try to navigate to the page by using `ContentFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<winrt::Program::SettingsPage>);`

The `DesktopWindowXamlSource`'s content is set to `ContentFrame`. Every time I try to navigate to the page, I get this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA08C08106 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

My Entrypoint and `WindowProc`:

```
#include "pchRT.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include "UIEngine.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static UI::UIEngine* uiEngine{ nullptr };

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        uiEngine = new UI::UIEngine{ reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE)), hWnd };
    break;
    case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
    {
        const auto mmInfo{ reinterpret_cast<LPMINMAXINFO>(lParam) };
        mmInfo->ptMinTrackSize.x = 876;
        mmInfo->ptMinTrackSize.y = 565;
    }
    break;
    case WM_SIZE:
        if (uiEngine)
        {
            //...
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        delete uiEngine;
        winrt::uninit_apartment();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
    PROCESS_MITIGATION_STRICT_HANDLE_CHECK_POLICY handlePolicy{0};
    handlePolicy.HandleExceptionsPermanentlyEnabled = 1;
    handlePolicy.RaiseExceptionOnInvalidHandleReference = 1;

    SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessStrictHandleCheckPolicy, &handlePolicy, sizeof PROCESS_MITIGATION_STRICT_HANDLE_CHECK_POLICY);
    WNDCLASSEXW wc{
        sizeof WNDCLASSEXW, CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProc, 0, 0, hInstance, nullptr,
        reinterpret_cast<HCURSOR>(LoadImageW(nullptr, IDC_ARROW, IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_SHARED)),
        reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT), nullptr, L"Settings Manager", nullptr
    };
    const auto hWnd{
        CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_LAYERED, MAKEINTATOM(RegisterClassExW(&wc)), L"Settings Manager", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, HWND_DESKTOP, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr)
    };
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`UIEngine` header:

```
#pragma once
#include "pchRT.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "MainPage.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace UI
{
    class UIEngine
    {
        HWND XamlIslandsWindow{}, CaptionIslandsWindow{}, Window;
        winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Hosting::DesktopWindowXamlSource DesktopWindowXamlSource;
        winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Hosting::DesktopWindowXamlSource CaptionXamlSource;
        winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Grid CaptionGrid, PanelGrid{ nullptr };
        winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame ContentFrame;
        bool HandleOverlap;
        RECT ClientArea;
        HINSTANCE AppInstance;
        winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream>
            ExtractAndLoadResource(
                int resourceId, LPCWSTR resourceType) const;
        static winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement FindElement(
            winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement const& startElement, PCWCH name);
    public:
        explicit UIEngine(HINSTANCE appInstance, HWND hWnd);

    };
}
```

`UIEngine` implementation:

```
#include "pchRT.h"
#include "UIEngine.h"
using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Composition;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;

namespace UI
{
    UIEngine::UIEngine(const HINSTANCE appInstance, const HWND hWnd) : Window(hWnd), HandleOverlap(false), AppInstance(appInstance)
    {
        init_apartment();
        auto windowInterop{ DesktopWindowXamlSource.as<IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative>() }, windowInterop2{
                 CaptionXamlSource.as<IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative>()
        };
        check_hresult(windowInterop->AttachToWindow(hWnd));
        check_hresult(windowInterop2->AttachToWindow(hWnd));
        windowInterop->get_WindowHandle(&XamlIslandsWindow);
        windowInterop2->get_WindowHandle(&CaptionIslandsWindow);
        ClientArea.top *= -1;
        SetWindowLongPtrW(CaptionIslandsWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE,
            GetWindowLongPtrW(CaptionIslandsWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        EnableWindow(CaptionIslandsWindow, FALSE);
        SetWindowPos(CaptionIslandsWindow, nullptr, 0, 1, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        SetWindowPos(XamlIslandsWindow, nullptr, 0, ClientArea.top, 0, 0,
            SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

        const Border captionBorder;
        const AcrylicBrush captionBorderBrush;
        captionBorderBrush.TintOpacity(0.65);
        captionBorderBrush.TintColor({ 255, 25, 25, 25 });
        captionBorderBrush.FallbackColor({ 255, 35, 35, 35 });
        captionBorderBrush.BackgroundSource(AcrylicBackgroundSource::HostBackdrop);
        captionBorder.Background(captionBorderBrush);
        captionBorder.HorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment::Left);
        captionBorder.Width(75);
        CaptionGrid.Children().Append(captionBorder);
        CaptionXamlSource.Content(CaptionGrid);
        ContentFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<winrt::Program::SettingsPage>());
    }
}
```

`pchRT.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <winrt/base.h>
#include <windows.ui.xaml.hosting.desktopwindowxamlsource.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Input.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Interop.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.h>
```

My call stack consists of these function calls:

```
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08c08106()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08c25edc()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08c27c22()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08c27da7()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08c27ead()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08c28006()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08c280e8()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08c281df()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08b7e225()  Unknown
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffa08b7e1af()  Unknown
>   Program.exe!winrt::impl::consume_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_INavigate<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame>::Navigate(const winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName & sourcePageType) Line 10998 C++
    Program.exe!UI::UIEngine::UIEngine(HINSTANCE__ * appInstance, HWND__ * hWnd, tagRECT clientArea) Line 123   C++
    Program.exe!WindowProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int msg, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 33    C++
    [External Code] 
    Program.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * __formal, wchar_t * __formal, int nCmdShow) Line 128    C++
    [External Code]
```

I am compiling my code with the C++/WinRT flag `-optimize`, and I have included `#include "UI.SettingsPage.g.cpp"`

Comment: A NULL pointer is clearly being accessed, you need to figure out where. When the AV happens, where does the debugger show you the error is actually happening? It should be giving you a call stack, if not the exact line of code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I edited my question to contain more information about the exception.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of actual code. The call stack you have shown suggests the crash is happening inside of your `WindowProc()` when it constructs a `UIEngine` object that tries to `Navigate()` and crashes. So what input is `WindowProc` providing to `UIEngine`?

Comment: Have you checked that ContentFrame is not null?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added all of my code, I hope it's not too much.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, I stepped through it with a debugger, `ContentFrame` is successfully initialized and is not `null`

Comment: `Frame contentFrame;` instantiates an object with automatic storage duration. Once code falls out of the `UIEngine` c'tor, the object gets destroyed. You will have to make sure that it lives for as long as the hosting window does.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, I made contentFrame private class variable, problem still persists.

Comment: Please update the question to reflect the changes. I'm not intimately familiar with XAML hosting, but I would guess that the XAML engine would need to discover user-authored elements (`MainPage` in this case). Does your application have a manifest, where you can register that element? Although I guess that failure to discover the element would raise a `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` exception. Still, try to see if [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50889858/1889329) has some useful information you can use.

Comment: It seems odd to navigate a frame before it has been added to the XAML tree. Is that allowed?

Comment: @IInspectable I don't understand what you want me to add to the question. Also, the Q&A doesn't really help me, as I am not getting a Class not registered exception.

Comment: @RaymondChen OK, I set my `DesktopWindowXamlSource` to my `ContentFrame`, then tried to navigate. Same error. BTW, the same problem happens for a `C++/WinRT Blank App`.

Comment: *"I made contentFrame private class variable"* - The code in the question does not reflect that.

Comment: @IInspectable I updated my code. I feel like this is a XAML framework problem as the error happens in other apps (including UWP) when you try to navigate to a page that's been created from an IDL definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this working. You need to follow these steps: [Custom Control XAML Hosting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands-cpp)

While following the steps, ignore the directions `Add a new UserControl` and add a `Page` instead. Then, in your desktop application, navigate to the page from a `Frame` created within the UWP app.