# Adding another window to WinUI3 project results in errors

Tags: xaml, winapi, winui-3

The idea is to create a DLL that can show WinUI3 dialogs to be used by a desktop application.

From File->New->Project I create a Blank App Packaged WinUI3

[image]

Then I compile the project and it shows a window, OK.
The files related to the main window are mainwindow.xaml, mainwindow.idl, mainwindow.xaml.cpp, mainwindow.xaml.h

Now I'm trying to add another, say an about dialog, with Add New Item -> XAML -> ContentDialog named "about.xaml". This time an IDL file is not generated and compilation fails with 'fatal  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'About.g.h': No such file or directory'.

When I manually edit the IDL file which originally contains:

```
namespace wui3
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainWindow : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window
    {
        MainWindow();
        Int32 MyProperty;
    }
}
```

and I add a:

```
runtimeclass About : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window
{
    About();
    Int32 MyProperty;
}
```

This generates about.g.h in "GeneratedFiles" but compilation still fails. As I see it, the .cpp files generated are C#, not C++.

So I tried once more, this time by generating a "Xaml View" from the New Item, which only generates a XAML.

```
<Window
    x:Class="wui3.About"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:wui3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This time xamltypeinfo.g.cpp compilation fails.

```
>XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp
1>F:\TP2\wui3\Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(144,55): error C2039: 'About': is not a member of 'winrt::wui3::implementation'
1>F:\TP2\wui3\Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(20,11): message : see declaration of 'winrt::wui3::implementation'
1>F:\TP2\wui3\Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(144,60): error C2275: 'winrt::wui3::About': expected an expression instead of a type
1>F:\TP2\wui3\Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(144,6): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable (__cdecl *)(void)'
1>F:\TP2\wui3\Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(144,6): message : None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
1>F:\TP2\wui3\Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(150,5): error C2078: too many initializers
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The tooling also generates files into *Generated Files\sources*. You'll need to copy (and adjust) those into your source tree, and reference them from the *.vcxproj*. Those files define the implementation types in the `implementation` namespace.

Comment: @IInspectable this doesn't change something.  Should I use the "Blank page" template or the "XAML view"?

Comment: @IInspectable "
// WARNING: This file is automatically generated by a tool. Do not directly
// add this file to your project, as any changes you make will be lost."

Comment: What the comment tries to communicate is that you should not add the files under *Generated Files\sources* to the *.vcxproj*. You'll have to copy them over, and reference those instead. You can then implement your logic into those copies, and update the copies from the *sources* whenever you make changes to the corresponding IDL files. As for the templates, I'm not familiar enough with them to make recommendations.

Comment: The ContentDialog you add by Add New Item -> XAML -> ContentDialog is a uwp dialog. You could add a uwp dialog in a winui3 project.

If you want to add a ContentDialog in winui3. I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [ContentDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2)

Comment: Also make sure to understand that C++/WinRT (in combination with XAML) is *very* sensitive to the order in which `#include` directives appear. If you get it wrong, the compiler (or linker) errors will not provide much help in guiding you.

Comment: @IInspectable from that I 've learned so far, the only way is to hardcopy MainWindow.* files (idl.xaml,h,cpp) generated for the main window to new ones and edit the class names and content. Also, this cannot be a DLL, it has to be a standalone executable (or at least I haven't found the way yet).

Comment: Copying from a known good state, and making adjustments as required, is certainly possible, even if tedious. But then, using XAML with anything that *isn't* C# is going to be tedious. Fixing that would need to get the Visual Studio team involved, and they don't have any interest in providing even just the bare minimum support on par with C++/CX. Regardless, I *think* you can compile UI components into WinRT components, so long as you properly manifest them. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50898168/1889329) might be relevant.

Comment: @IInspectable yes it worked. My [current problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76068980/winui3-multiple-window-opening)  is how to reuse the executable.