# WinUI3 multiple window opening

Tags: xaml, winapi, winui-3

I 've created a WinUI3 executable to be able to show newer UI style dialog boxes when called from my main Win32 app.

Now this would show the main window in this:

```
::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start(
    [](auto&&)
    {
       ::winrt::make<::winrt::wui3::implementation::App>();
    });
```

When the window exits (Close()) called, this returns. I can't call again to display another window, it crashes.

Is there anyway to work through this?

The idea is to have the WinUI3 app wait on a mutex for a trigger by the Win32 app, exchange data with shared memory, show the requested dialog and loop that until signalled to close.

I haven't found the way to create it as a DLL yet.

Comment: Did you consider [Using the WinRT XAML hosting API in a C++ desktop (Win32) app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-xaml-hosting-api)? Do you use CreateProcess to launch the WinUI3 executable? Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Comment: That api does not work well and doesnt support many controls. I have created a library for it https://github.com/WindowsNT/uwplib

Comment: At a guess, [`Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.application.start) decommissions the [`DispatcherQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.dispatching.dispatcherqueue) once *The* window is closed (remember, this is all based off of the UWP, where Windows 10 Mobile applications were confined to a single window). I guess you'd have to create your own `DispatcherQueue`, though I'm unsure what this week's current dispatcher is.

Comment: I think I don't really want to mess with that. Perhaps another approach is to have all my Xaml as content dialogs.

Comment: @IInspectable that's finally how I did it, with single Xaml with many sub StackPanels. My article is [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5359576/WinUI3-in-existing-Win32-applications).